# Displaying a list of assignable YouTube categories

Tags: youtube-api, uipickerview, categories

I am uploading video from my app to YouTube. I have this completed, but there is a small hitch. I use picker to allow the user to select the category of the video. I am trying to use the categories listed by Apple in their upload page which includes items such as "Autos & Vehicles". However if you look at the categories accepted by YouTube this one is "Autos". To deal with this I create the Array for the Picker using "Autos & Vehicles" but then later I convert these to "Autos".

I do this using the following code.

```
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init ];
    [pickerArray addObject: @"Autos & Vehicles" ];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Comedy"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Education"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Entertainment"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Film & Animation"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Gaming"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Howto & Style"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Music"];
   [pickerArray addObject:@"News & Politics"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Nonprofits & Activism"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"People & Blogs"];
   [pickerArray addObject:@"Pets & Animals"];
     [pickerArray addObject:@"Science & Technology"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Sports"];
    [pickerArray addObject:@"Travel & Events"];

    [catagoryPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    catagoryField1.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:[catagoryPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

//and then to convert this code


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    catagoryField1.text = [pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];

    if (catagoryField1.text == @"Comedy") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Comedy";
    }
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Autos & Vehicles") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Autos";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Gaming") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Games";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Education") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Education";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Entertainment") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Entertainment";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Film & Animation") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Film";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Howto & Style") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Howto";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Music") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Music";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"News & Politics") {
        catagoryField.text =@"News";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Nonprofits & Activism") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Nonprofit";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"People & Blogs") {
        catagoryField.text =@"People";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Pets & Animals") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Animals";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Science & Technology") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Tech";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Sports") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Sports";}
    else if (catagoryField1.text == @"Travel & Events") {
        catagoryField.text =@"Travel";}
}
```

This works when there is only a single word like "Gaming" but it doesn't work when using "Autos & Vehicles". If I use "Autos / Vehicles" it doesn't work but "Autos/Vehicles" does. So I am assuming that the use of spaces messes something up. Can someone tell me how to fix this so I can use "Autos & Vehicles".

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#YouTube_Category_List

Basically, each category has a `term` value (which is what you pass in to the API) and a `label` value (which is what you show in your UI). Those docs explain how to retrieve a list of those values in an XML file and how to determine what to show.

Answer (score 1):

To get `All categories` in `YouTube` according to `country wise` then use `GET Request` :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?key={your public access api key here}&part=snippet&regionCode=IN
```

**Note** : regionCode is the parameter value is an [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm) country code.